# Breaking an array into groups based on values

Tags: php, arrays

Using PHP, I'm trying to break an array up into multiple arrays based on groups of values. The groups are based on the values being between 1 and 5. But here's the hard part...

I need to loop through the array and put the first set of values that are between 1 and 5 in their own array, then the next set of values that are between 1 and 5 in their own array, and so on.

But each group WON'T always include 1,2,3,4,5. Some groups could be random.

Examples:

1,1,2,2,3,4,5 - this would be a group

1,2,3,4,4,4 - this would be a group

1,2,3,3,5 - this would be a group

2,2,3,3,5 - this would be a group

So I can't just test for specific numbers.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 4
    [9] => 4
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 1
    [12] => 3
    [13] => 4
    [14] => 5
)
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just check if the current value is larger than the previous value, and if yes, begin a new group.

```
$groups = array();
$groupcount = 1;

foreach( $array as $key=>$value )
{
    if( $key > 0 )  // there's no "previous value" for the first entry
    {
        if( $array[$key] < $array[$key-1] )
        {
            $groupcount = $groupcount + 1;
        }
    }

    $group[groupcount][] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$groups = array();
$cur = array();
$prev = 0;
foreach ($numbers as $number)
{
  if ($number < $prev)
  {
    $groups[] = $cur;
    $cur = array();
  }
  $cur[] = $number;
  $prev = $number;
}
if ($cur) $groups[] = $cur;
```

Untested. (Edit: corrected some obvious mistakes.)