# array_chunk with callback/value instead of interval?

Tags: php

I want to create a multi array by breaking an array at each date value:

```
array(
    '3/20/13', // date (start a new child array)
    '14',
    'dog',
    'red',
    '10/21/13', // date (start a new child array)
    '3',
    'cat'
)
```

I wrote a complex `foreach` function which built a new array by detecting whether the value was a date:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/d/y', $value);
```

I was wondering if there was an easier way to split the array or do I have to individually go through each value? My concern is that `array_chunk` works for an interval, but does not have **any** variation to that. I am seriously surprised if PHP cannot chunk at a callback.

*I am aware that there is a similar question asked, but the answers were manual looping through each value.* ([Breaking an array into groups based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007989/breaking-an-array-into-groups-based-on-values?rq=1)).

Comment: How do you expect to do this without a loop? Plus if they work, why *wouldn't* you use it?

Comment: @JohnConde PHP has so many little magic functions, I was hoping for a clever `array_map` solution or something. Possibly there is a function I am missing?

Comment: This is much too specific for their to be a dedicated function for it

Comment: @JohnConde It's essentially `array_chunk` only with a date value instead of an interval. I don't think that is too specific. In fact, I think it is basic enough to be somewhere... hence the question.

Comment: Kinda sounds like you already know the solution. Why don't you post what you've tried?

Comment: @JohnConde What I tried produced a few empty elements, which I wasn't able to filter out. I posted here in hopes of a function I was missing, if that function doesn't exist, then I will proceed to work out the errors in the manual method. I didn't want to post my function, because it didn't seem relevant. I am not asking for someone to fix my errors.

Comment: @JohnConde I will change the question to be more open and relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [x] Tested and working.
- [ ] Less complicated than your foreach loop? :)

  ```
  // Source array to break into child arrays based on regular expression delimiter
  $array = array(
      '3/20/13', // date (start a new child array)
      '14',
      'dog',
      'red',
      '10/21/13', // date (start a new child array)
      '3',
      'cat',
      '01/02/03', // another example
      '4',
      'badger'
  );

  // Regular expression to break array into child arrays
  $delimiter = '/\//';

  // Finds index position of matching delimiter in array (e.g. 0, 4)
  $childIndex = array_keys(preg_grep($delimiter, $array));

  // For each matching delimiter get the beginning index position and length of entries before next child begins - they part that array_chunk doesn't support. We feed these begin/length into array_slice next to make our own array
  for ($i=0; $i<count($childIndex); $i++):
      $chunks[$i]['begin'] = $childIndex[$i];
      // Last chunk doesn't need a length
      if (isset($childIndex[$i+1])):
          $chunks[$i]['len'] = $childIndex[$i+1]-$childIndex[$i];
      endif;
  endfor;

  // For each begin/length chunk splice the source array into a child array
  foreach ($chunks as $chunk):
      if (isset($chunk['len'])):
          $final[] = array_slice($array, $chunk['begin'], $chunk['len']);
      else:
          $final[] = array_slice($array, $chunk['begin']);
      endif;
  endforeach;

  // Our new nested array
  var_dump($final);
  ```

**Results**

```
// Source
array (size=10)
  0 => string '3/20/13' (length=7)
  1 => string '14' (length=2)
  2 => string 'dog' (length=3)
  3 => string 'red' (length=3)
  4 => string '10/21/13' (length=8)
  5 => string '3' (length=1)
  6 => string 'cat' (length=3)
  7 => string '01/02/03' (length=8)
  8 => string '4' (length=1)
  9 => string 'badger' (length=6)

// Found delimiter positions
array (size=3)
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 4
  2 => int 7

// Chunks
array (size=2)
  'begin' => int 0
  'len' => int 4
array (size=2)
  'begin' => int 4
  'len' => int 3
array (size=1)
  'begin' => int 7

// Final nested array
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '3/20/13' (length=7)
      1 => string '14' (length=2)
      2 => string 'dog' (length=3)
      3 => string 'red' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '10/21/13' (length=8)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'cat' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '01/02/03' (length=8)
      1 => string '4' (length=1)
      2 => string 'badger' (length=6)
```

Comment: You should put a better regular expression pattern in for $delimiter to match your date format as this is merely matching '/'.

Comment: jeez looking at this, I feel like I don't even know how to code lol! I will try to work through what you've done. Thanks for an answer! :D

Comment: I edited it with better notes for you. It's just a matter of finding the position in the array where you want to split the array, then splitting the array using `array_slice` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php